# Use monit to collect metrics?

Tags: monitoring, monit, system-monitoring

`monit` is very useful, simple and stable tool, but one thing is curious:

Is it possible to log every `monit` check?

I mean, that it logs only errors, like

```
[MSK Aug 10 15:54:30] error    : 'fs-home' space usage 96.0% matches resource limit [space usage>80.0%]
```

and I want to get something like:

```
[MSK Aug 10 15:54:30] info    : 'fs-home' space usage 50.0% matches resource limit [space usage>80.0%]
```

Comment: you question is quite unclear, could you elaborate what you want and why?
do you want to log each and every check execution? do you want to log performance data from each check?

Comment: thanks, @madeddie. i've updated with some explanation.
what i want - is to redirect `monit` to `logstash`.

Comment: ah, I see, I don't think that's possible, since monit is specifically designed to notify on failure, for metrics I'd advise to use a more specialized tool, like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/).